# StackOverflowError when using Jetpack Compose @Preview in Android project

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-preview

I'm facing an issue when trying to use the Jetpack Compose `@Preview` annotation in my Android project. Whenever I try to preview a Composable function, I encounter a `java.lang.StackOverflowError`.

Here are my `build.gradle` file:

```
    plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
}

android {
    namespace = "ir.gando"
    compileSdk = 34
    
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "ir.gando"
        minSdk = 24
        //noinspection EditedTargetSdkVersion
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"
        
        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }
    
    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.4.3"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    
    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.2")
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.8.1")
    implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00"))
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3")
    debugImplementation ("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.7.5")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    androidTestImplementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00"))
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest")
}
```

here is the error:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at androidx.compose.runtime.ParcelableSnapshotMutableState.<init>(ParcelableSnapshotMutableState.kt:27)
at androidx.compose.runtime.ActualAndroid_androidKt.createSnapshotMutableState(ActualAndroid.android.kt:93)
at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt__SnapshotStateKt.mutableStateOf(SnapshotState.kt:61)
at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt.mutableStateOf(Unknown Source)
at androidx.compose.material3.ColorScheme.<init>(ColorScheme.kt:131)
at androidx.compose.material3.ColorScheme.<init>(ColorScheme.kt)
at androidx.compose.material3.ColorSchemeKt.lightColorScheme-G1PFc-w(ColorScheme.kt:323)
at androidx.compose.material3.ColorSchemeKt.lightColorScheme-G1PFc-w$default(ColorScheme.kt:292)
at androidx.compose.material3.DynamicTonalPaletteKt.dynamicLightColorScheme(DynamicTonalPalette.kt:118)
at ir.gando.ui.theme.ThemeKt.GandoAndroidTheme(Theme.kt:50)
at ir.gando.ui.screen.MainScreenKt.MainScreenPreView(MainScreen.kt:25)
at ir.gando.ui.screen.ComposableSingletons$MainScreenKt$lambda-2$1.invoke(MainScreen.kt:26)
at ir.gando.ui.screen.ComposableSingletons$MainScreenKt$lambda-2$1.invoke(MainScreen.kt:25)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:108)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
at androidx.compose.material3.TextKt.ProvideTextStyle(Text.kt:261)
at androidx.compose.material3.MaterialThemeKt$MaterialTheme$1.invoke(MaterialTheme.kt:81)
at androidx.compose.material3.MaterialThemeKt$MaterialTheme$1.invoke(MaterialTheme.kt:80)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:108)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
at androidx.compose.material3.MaterialThemeKt.MaterialTheme(MaterialTheme.kt:73)
at ir.gando.ui.theme.ThemeKt.GandoAndroidTheme(Theme.kt:65)
at ir.gando.ui.screen.MainScreenKt.MainScreenPreView(MainScreen.kt:25)
at ir.gando.ui.screen.ComposableSingletons$MainScreenKt$lambda-2$1.invoke(MainScreen.kt:26)
at ir.gando.ui.screen.ComposableSingletons$MainScreenKt$lambda-2$1.invoke(MainScreen.kt:25)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:108)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
at androidx.compose.material3.TextKt.ProvideTextStyle(Text.kt:261)
at androidx.compose.material3.MaterialThemeKt$MaterialTheme$1.invoke(MaterialTheme.kt:81)
at androidx.compose.material3.MaterialThemeKt$MaterialTheme$1.invoke(MaterialTheme.kt:80)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:108)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
at androidx.compose.material3.MaterialThemeKt.MaterialTheme(MaterialTheme.kt:73)
at ir.gando.ui.theme.ThemeKt.GandoAndroidTheme(Theme.kt:65)
at ir.gando.ui.screen.MainScreenKt.MainScreenPreView(MainScreen.kt:25)
at ir.gando.ui.screen.ComposableSingletons$MainScreenKt$lambda-2$1.invoke(MainScreen.kt:26)
at ir.gando.ui.screen.ComposableSingletons$MainScreenKt$lambda-2$1.invoke(MainScreen.kt:25)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:108)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
at androidx.compose.material3.TextKt.ProvideTextStyle(Text.kt:261)
at androidx.compose.material3.MaterialThemeKt$MaterialTheme$1.invoke(MaterialTheme.kt:81)
at androidx.compose.material3.MaterialThemeKt$MaterialTheme$1.invoke(MaterialTheme.kt:80)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:108)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
at omitted.omitted(omitted)
at androidx.compose.material3.MaterialThemeKt.MaterialTheme(MaterialTheme.kt:73)
at ir.gando.ui.theme.ThemeKt.GandoAndroidTheme(Theme.kt:65)
at ir.gando.ui.screen.MainScreenKt.MainScreenPreView(MainScreen.kt:25)
at ir.gando.ui.screen.ComposableSingletons$MainScreenKt$lambda-2$1.invoke(MainScreen.kt:26)
at ir.gando.ui.screen.ComposableSingletons$MainScreenKt$lambda-2$1.invoke(MainScreen.kt:25)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:108)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
at androidx.compose.material3.TextKt.ProvideTextStyle(Text.kt:261)
at androidx.compose.material3.MaterialThemeKt$MaterialTheme$1.invoke(MaterialTheme.kt:81)
at androidx.compose.material3.MaterialThemeKt$MaterialTheme$1.invoke(MaterialTheme.kt:80)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:108)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
at androidx.compose.material3.MaterialThemeKt.MaterialTheme(MaterialTheme.kt:73)
at ir.gando.ui.theme.ThemeKt.GandoAndroidTheme(Theme.kt:65)
at ir.gando.ui.screen.MainScreenKt.MainScreenPreView(MainScreen.kt:25)
at ir.gando.ui.screen.ComposableSingletons$MainScreenKt$lambda-2$1.invoke(MainScreen.kt:26)
at ir.gando.ui.screen.ComposableSingletons$MainScreenKt$lambda-2$1.invoke(MainScreen.kt:25)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:108)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
at androidx.compose.material3.TextKt.ProvideTextStyle(Text.kt:261)
at androidx.compose.material3.MaterialThemeKt$MaterialTheme$1.invoke(MaterialTheme.kt:81)
at androidx.compose.material3.MaterialThemeKt$MaterialTheme$1.invoke(MaterialTheme.kt:80)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:108)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
at androidx.compose.material3.MaterialThemeKt.MaterialTheme(MaterialTheme.kt:73)
at ir.gando.ui.theme.ThemeKt.GandoAndroidTheme(Theme.kt:65)
at ir.gando.ui.screen.MainScreenKt.MainScreenPreView(MainScreen.kt:25)
at ir.gando.ui.screen.ComposableSingletons$MainScreenKt$lambda-2$1.invoke(MainScreen.kt:26)
at ir.gando.ui.screen.ComposableSingletons$MainScreenKt$lambda-2$1.invoke(MainScreen.kt:25)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:108)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
at androidx.compose.material3.TextKt.ProvideTextStyle(Text.kt:261)
at androidx.compose.material3.MaterialThemeKt$MaterialTheme$1.invoke(MaterialTheme.kt:81)
at androidx.compose.material3.MaterialThemeKt$MaterialTheme$1.invoke(MaterialTheme.kt:80)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:108)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
at androidx.compose.material3.MaterialThemeKt.MaterialTheme(MaterialTheme.kt:73)
at ir.gando.ui.theme.ThemeKt.GandoAndroidTheme(Theme.kt:65)
at ir.gando.ui.screen.MainScreenKt.MainScreenPreView(MainScreen.kt:25)
at ir.gando.ui.screen.ComposableSingletons$MainScreenKt$lambda-2$1.invoke(MainScreen.kt:26)
at ir.gando.ui.screen.ComposableSingletons$MainScreenKt$lambda-2$1.invoke(MainScreen.kt:25)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:108)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
```